# Filter rows in rhandsontable in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, filter, shiny, rhandsontable

I want to display and edit an `rhandsontable` within a Shiny app. Since my data frame is fairly large, I want the user to be able to filter a specific row instead of displaying the whole 1000 rows (see example below). I can create a reactive value to subset `hot` based on `input$row`, but then only `DF[input$row,]` is assigned to `input$hot` and, thus, next time I get the value of `input$hot` it returns a data frame with only one row.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  numericInput("rows","row to filter",value = 1),
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # render handsontable output
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
      DF <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    } else {
      set.seed(42)
      DF <- data.frame(a=1:1000, b= rnorm(1000))
    }
    rhandsontable(DF) 
  })

})

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Is there a filtering paramenter that I can apply to `rhandsontable()` that would allow me to render a filtered version of my data frame without actually subsetting it, so that the linked `input$hot` wouldn't be affected (except, of course, for any edits made by the user)?

I want the user to write the row to filter in the textInput box `row` and then the table to be filtered accordingly. It is imperative that `nrow(hot_to_r(input$hot)) == 1000` continues to be TRUE:

[image: render]

Comment: What do you mean by a "filtered version without subsetting" ? What do you want to render ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, added expected rendering. The problem I have is that if I choose to subset DF by something like `DF[rows,]` (in a reactive way, of course) then the subset DF is saved back to `input$hot` and I lose the other 999 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like that, with a filter, but you can cache a row, and put the data back when things change.

This is one way to do it in Shiny. Way harder to get right than I thought, I tried quite a few other ways that did not work, so it was a learning experience for me too.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

set.seed(1234)

# Data and a couple utility functions
nrow <- 1000
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:nrow,b = abs(rnorm(nrow)))
lastrow <- 1

getrowfromDF <- function(idx) {
  return(DF[idx,])
}

putrowintoDF <- function(rowdf,idx) {
  for (ic in 1:ncol(DF)) {
    DF[idx,ic] <<- rowdf[1,ic]
  }
}

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  numericInput("row","row to filter",value = lastrow,min = 1,max = nrow(DF)),
  verbatimTextOutput("rowstat"),
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")
))

s <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {

  # reactive row status
  rs <- reactiveValues()
  rs$lstrow <- rs$currow <- 1

  # record changes from user editing here
  observeEvent(input$hot, {
    if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
      ndf <- data.frame(input$hot$data)  # convert from list
      #putrowintoDF(ndf,rs$currow)   # original - has inconsistency issue when 
                                     # you change rows without closing edit
                                     # with enter key in rhandsontable grid input$hot
      putrowintoDF(ndf,ndf[1,1])     # new, consistent, but relies on editable data for state
    }
  })

  # slide the row to the new position here
  observeEvent(input$row, {
    rs$lstrow <<- rs$currow
    rs$currow <<- input$row
  })


  # render handsontable output
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    ndf <- getrowfromDF(rs$currow)
    rhandsontable(ndf)
  })

  # just for debug
  output$rowstat <- renderPrint({ sprintf("rowstat: cur:%d last:%d",rs$currow,rs$lstrow) })

})
shinyApp(ui = u,server = s)
```

I would have liked a solution without global variable assignment and pure reactives instead of observes, but I don't think it is possible.

## Update

The orginal I posed had a consistency error I missed because I was using a version of Shiny without the numeric control increment arrows. It happened when you changed the row with the numeric control `input$row`, without closing the edit in the rhandsontable `input$hot` with an enter key or change in focus, and caused the wrong row to be updated in the dataframe `DF`.

The fix is using data in `input$hot` to maintain this state, but that is perhaps dangerous as the user could edit that. Or maybe that is a feature...

Any way, here is a screen shot, but you really have to play with the values to see that it works and has no bugs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by conditionally hiding rows: https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/219#issuecomment-487574898